# Replacing/removing a base64 encoded image and link from web page or CSS

Tags: css, base64

I am using the web/wap script (wapdesire) which has base64-encoded images in the background of index.php. I am trying to locate the images so that I can remove/delete one, but I can't get a physical location.

From web developer I can see the  CSS details of this base64 image, but as I mentioned I don't know the images **physical location and how to remove it**.

Embedded Styles from http://icombined.hostei.com/web/index.php:

```
body {
    background: url(data: image/png; base64, iVBORw0 ... Y%2Fsfiv02O7iVu1LunAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

Comment: A `base64` image can exist only in a textual format, meaning there may be no root file reference (as a regular file could be "seen" in a file explorer). You would have to find out where the source code for that CSS was located and change the CSS source.

Answer (score 5):

The `iVBORw0KGgo…` string ***is the image*** itself.  You need only find what file contains that string, or what file/s contain the string 'base64' and either remove the string or the code that generates it.

The image, encoded in base64, is present as part of a value for the background property of the body rule inside a style element.  Chances are this is in a header file somewhere and not in that particular `index.php` file itself.  It might be in the 404 ErrorDocument file configured to be used by your web server, Apache, or it might be in a file which that file refers to.

Looking at it now, your ultimate problem seems to be less that there is a background image on this page and more that you seem to be including accidentally a resource that does not exist ([404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)).

Near the end of what appears to be your intended source it starts to get hairy:

`<p align="center"><a href="img src=//www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif alt=Google">`

At this point or shortly after it the server is deciding you're asking for something that doesn't exist, and injecting its 404 document.

Look again at your code and make sure it is sane.

Comment: So how do i remove if the image is in CSS and  in Embbeded styles. To clarify  make my questtion  is  where am i supppose to  find  phsyically   nd edit the embeded styles of  a page? here is the page am tallking  about http://icombined.hostei.com/web/index.php

Comment: Responded in answer so it'd fit.

Comment: @resio  Usingt the web developer tool   the base64 ennocoe d image ias seen as backgroun imge of the body. But supirisngly  I have tried installing another version of the scrip in  another web server ( http://teknohama.x10.mx/poa/web/index.php)  that image  doesnt display. But  when i use the same version of the scrip in 000webhot server ( http://icombined.hostei.com/givenality/web/index.php) the unwanted image re-appaer . Could it be a the site is hacked?

Comment: Technically yes, but it'd be a pretty weird hack if all they did was inject some 404 page.  It's more likely the servers differ, differ in configuration, or in resource availability.

Comment: Don't know about the 404, but if trying to remove the background image, just remove the Base64 string from the css, or replace it with something else. You can encode your own images here : http://www.base64img.com